# A Basic Math Question on Averages

Tags: average

Okay this is going to sound really stupid but I'll ask anyway...

I need to get a $5.5$ accumulative GPA (the highest is a $7.0$). For the last $16$ classes I've done my GPA is sitting at $5.44$. I'm taking $3$ classes this semester, what would I need to get it up to $5.5$ if:

- Credit = $5.0$
- Distinction = $6.0$
- High Distinction = $7.0$

Thanks!

Comment: What is the sum of your grades so far? Is it $87$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the sum of your grades is $87$ so far, making the average now $$\frac{87}{16} = 5.4375\approx5.44$$

Let $x$ denote the sum of your remaining three grades. Then the average of all your $19$ grades will be equal to the sum of your grades divided by $19$. The sum of your $19$ grades is of course $87+x$, meaning that you want to know the value of $x$ for which $$\frac{87+x}{19}\geq 5.5.$$

I trust you are able to solve this equation?

Comment: Wonderful way of putting it, thanks for helping out. I really had no idea what I was doing.